# What is 'term' expression in jQueryUI autocomplete function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using an jQueryUI autocomplete function to read data from database. Autocomplete calls an PHP script, which is looking next:

```
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE name LIKE '%$text%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$exe = '[';
$first = true;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(!$first)
            {
                $exe .=  ','; 
            }
            else
            {
                $first = false;
            }
            $exe .= '{"value":"'.$row['fname'].', '.$row['lname'].'. "}';
            }
            $exe .= ']';
            echo $exe; 
}
```

As I could understand, PHP code saves matching data to JSON array of objects called exe, but what I don't understand is:

```
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
```

What is this? My input field is called 'name', and I even don't use method $_GET, but $_POST. Is the 'term' something which autocomplete function adds by default? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, term is passed automatically by the autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 0):

the PHP

$_GET['term']

retrieves the value of term= from the get string.  Since that is provided by the user/user's browser it is a non-trusted value.  In order to protect you from some common sql injection attacks, it is filtered through the mysqli_real_escape_string function to escape any sql-active characters.